# Creating multiple folders ending with iterative numbers (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8

So I'm trying to create 60 folders with a name and different numbers at the end iteratively.  So like Name_1, Name_2, Name_3, ect.  Without typing out all 60 names.  I found this link

[How to batch create a range of folders (000-999) in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/201230/how-to-batch-create-a-range-of-folders-000-999-in-windows?newreg=1ef425932b784ba192b327d5c9e24d1e)

But I'm a little unclear as how to modify the code to have the name aspect at the beginning of each file.

Comment: Having read the link to modify the code, where are you unclear? :)

Comment: I had some syntax issues but I figured them out.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /l %i in (0,1,9) do md Name_00%i
for /l %i in (10,1,99) do md Name_0%i
for /l %i in (100,1,999) do md Name_%i
```